# Reversing a string operation

Tags: algorithm

So I was fiddling with my encryption algorithms when this problem caught my attention:

Suppose you have a string operation given by the following pseudocode:

```
string go_wacky(string input, int reps)
{
    string result = input;
    foreach (0..reps)
    {
        result = insert_substring_at(result, input, random_from_to(0, length(result));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or, in point-and-click terminology, copy the string, then reps times do the following: move the cursor to a random position within the string and hit paste.

Given the output string and reps, how to extract the input string (other than "reverse brute force" based on reconstructing the character list of the original string using reps and output length)?

Comment: Can't be solved if input contains substring as one cannot decide which of the substrings belonged in input originally. So you need to specify if that's a problem.

Comment: @Mel: if the input string contains an exact number of repetition of a substring, and no other character, then the algorithm will find the substring and not the original input string. if there is any other character mixed between the substring, then the algorithm should be possible (although quite hard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the chars of the input string, by counting the frequencies of all the chars and dividing by `rep count + 1`. For example, if `a` is 12 times in the output, and rep count is 2. Then the input string is contained `2+1` times in the output and thus contains `12/3 = 4` `a`'s.

Next, look at the first char of the output, that is the first char of the input aswell. Subtract one from its frequency.

For the next char, we do a branch.

- It is the start of the input: Just continue.
- **or**, it is the second char of the input. Decrease the frequency and continue.

Pretty much the same procedure for the following chars.

For example, if the output starts with `aa...`. When reading the second `a`, the input can be `a...` and `aa...`. (Unless, the frequency of `a` is 1.)

I think this should be quite fast. In the case the frequencies are all one, this is O(n) with n size of the output string.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not too brute-force, but I see no other way:

Take the first character of the output (call it a) and the last character of the output (call it b).

Search the output for substrings of length len(output)/reps starting with a and ending with b. This yields a list of candidates.

For each candidate replace recursively inside the output the candidate with an empty string, i.e. output = output.replace (candidate, '')

If after the last replacement, the result is an empty string you found the plain text.

Answer (score 0):

just some random thoughts:

- the input appears completely at least once in the output.
- this problem may resolve to the ["longest substring"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Length of the output = N repeats * size of the input string.

This isn't guaranteed solvable without some better clue about the input string size or repetition count.

Comment: "Given the output string and reps", so repetition count is given.

Comment: I have no hard mathematical proof so far, but I have the strong suspicion that it is always solvable no matter the input and the number of repetitions. If you can come up with an unsolvable example or an ambiguous example (as a negative proof of my theory), it would be very appreciated.